# HTML Comments Generator

Tags: html, text, comments, generator, ascii-art

This may seem like an odd question, but I'm looking for a comment generator for HTML language. Although I'm sure the same applies to any language.

What I mean by a comment generator is that when you comment out code in HTML to remind yourself what bits do what, you would just do `<!-- Title -->` right?

But I've seen this developer that has massive 'commented out titles' for huge chucks of code he's working on so he doesn't get lost. The actual 'commented out text' is made up of characters making it appear like its actual text. Its kind'a hard to explain, but I'll try my best to do a rough example below:

```
|||||||||.||.|||||||||.||.....||||||
...||.....||....||.....||.....|||...
...||.....||....||.....||.....||....
...||.....||....||.....||||||.||||||
```

Humm.. that worked better than expected, but you get what I mean right?
Just wondering if there's a generator out there that does this for me.

I don't even know what this 'art form' is called.

Thanks

Comment: ASCII art. There's something called AAlib but it doesn't necessarily apply to HTML comments specifically.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as tool recommendation. Also consider: `sudo apt-get install toilet && echo abcdef | toilet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "art form" is often called "ASCII art". You can find an online generator at [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/).

Comment: Ah, I found a cool generator: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/ Sooo many to choose from! I have no idea! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose you can use any online Text to ASCII converter. There are many sites available online. A sample site: [link](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/). Hope it helps!